# WhereHas method in Sequelize

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

Sequelize reminds me Eloquent library in Laravel, but I can't find anything similar to method **WhereHas** that allows filtering records using associated tables.

Say, I need to select all users in the group with ID = 1, then I can use the query below, but then I have to extract users from results.

```
let group = group.findOne({
  include: [{
    as: 'users',
    model: schema.users
  }],
  where: {
    id: groupId
  }
})

let users = group.users;
```

Is there a method like WhereHas that I could use to create a query for users only and then filter them using association with groups?

```
let users = group.findAll({
  whereHas: [{
    as: 'groups',
    model: schema.groups,
    where: {
      id: groupId      // something like this, group is used for filtering only
    }
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and my solution is `required:true` in include option. If you want to find all users that join a group, you can use code below:

```
let users = users.findAll({
  include: [{
    as: 'groups',
    model: schema.groups,
    required:true,
    where: {
      id: groupId      
    }
  }],
})
```

Comment: This is not working on my end. It still filter all the rows with no match on the id